# Installation - Coffee not recognised

Tags: coffeescript, installation

I'm following [this](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-absolute-beginners-guide-to-coffeescript) tutorial to install coffee in my machine. I also use [this](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation) tutorial to install nodejs. After the installation, i types `coffee-v` in my cmd but **coffee** not recognised. Please advice.

Image
[image]

Comment: whats the reason for downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `c:\users\penangIT\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script\bin` to your `PATH` environment variable.

[Here's how:](https://superuser.com/a/284351/4377)

> 1. Open `Control Panel » System » Advanced » Environment Variables`. Another open source program for Windows with.
> 2. Find Path & edit to to include the above path at the end after a semi-colon (`;`)
>
>    - You can also edit the path environment using [Path
>        Editor](http://www.redfernplace.com/software-projects/patheditor/).